# How to add users to Administrators group in new Azure API Management Developer Portal when only using Azure AD Identity?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have an API Management instance running where users can login using only Azure AD. There is a single Administrators account, but it is using the legacy User/Password Identity. I cannot remove the user. I want to assign a user from the Azure AD to the Administrators group, but I can not figure out how.

[I have followed these steps by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-faq#how-do-i-add-a-user-to-the-administrators-group) but they just seem to redirect me to the legacy portal (or the new Developer portal if I change the URL normally) with my default Administrators account logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, we can't add another user into "Administrators" group.

[image]

The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-faq#how-do-i-add-a-user-to-the-administrators-group) you provided is used to login another user(which is not admin) as administrator. So the result page shows your default administrators account. The title "**How do I add a user to the Administrators group?**" of the document is not very accurate.

Comment: Thanks Hury. Disappointing answer and indeed an inaccurate title.